# how to toggle hiding other elements after button clicks react js?

Tags: reactjs

i have managed to toggle tables upon button clicks but i want for each table to only show when its button is clicked and then hide when another button meant for another table is clicked. where do i need to make changes and what do i need to add for it to work accordingly? This is the code im using currently:

```
const [show, toggleShow] = useState({}); 
const [showStock, toggleShowStock] = useState({});
const [showEcartStock,toggleShowEcartStock]=useState({});
<Layout>
      <Content
         style={{
           margin: 0,
           backgroundColor: "white",
         }}
       >
         <div
           className="site-layout-background"
           style={{
             padding: 24,
             minHeight: 360,
           }}
         >
           <Home sessionName={session_name} sessionID={state}  session_status={session_status}/>
           <div style={{ heigth: "80vh",margin: "16px" }}>
        <Row
          gutter={[13, 5]}
          justify="center"
          align="top"
        >
          <Col
          onClick={() => toggleShowStock(!showStock)}>
            <Button
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "#5e89af",
                color: "white",
                //padding: '18px 40px',
                height: "60px",
                width: "325px",
                alignItems: "center",
            }}
            >
              état stock
            </Button>
          </Col>

           <Col onClick={() => toggleShow(!show)}>
            <Button
              style={{
                backgroundColor: "#5e89af",
                color: "white",
                height: "60px",
                width: "325px",
                alignItems: "center",
              }}
            >
              affectation
            </Button>
          </Col> 

          <Col
          >
            <Button
              onClick={()=>{toggleShowEcartStock(!showEcartStock)}}
              style={{
                backgroundColor: "#5e89af",
                color: "white",
                height: "60px",
                width: "325px",
                alignItems: "center",
              }}
            >
              écart stock
            </Button>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
            {show && (
             <AffectaionsTable sessionType={session_type} sessionName={session_name} sessionID={state} />
           )}
      
           {showStock && <StocksTable record={record} sessionID={state}/>}
           {showEcartStock && <EcartStockRes sessionID={state}/>}
           {showEcartStock && <EcartStockComTour sessionID={state}/>}
           {showEcartStock && <EcartStockTechTour sessionID={state}/>}
           </div>
       </Content>
    
     </Layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `onClick` function and set `show` and `showEcartStock` to false when `showStock` is true

here is an eg:

```
const handleClick = (e, val) => {
 if (val === 'showStock') {
   toggleShowStock(true);
   toggleShowEcartStock(false);
   toggleShow(false)
 }
 else if (like the above change accordingly......)
}
```

Then use this function in `onClick`

```
<Col
          onClick={handleClick('showStock')}>
            <Button
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "#5e89af",
                color: "white",
                //padding: '18px 40px',
                height: "60px",
                width: "325px",
                alignItems: "center",
            }}
            >
              état stock
            </Button>
          </Col>
```